# Xamarin Shiny Push

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to use Shiny Push for my Xamarin app but the OnTokenChanged (in the push Delegate) does not get called, on Android.  It works find on iOS.  Has anyone experienced this?

I register the delegate in startup

```cs
  services.UsePush<PushDelegate>();
```

I then call Push Manager's Request Access

```cs
var result = await _pushManager.RequestAccess();
```

The result comes back with the correct status of Available and it has a device token in the response too but the Push delegate's OnTokenChanged does not run.

Shiny is registered in my MainActivity (Shiny 2 version)

```cs
[assembly: ShinyApplication(
    ShinyStartupTypeName = "AddView.Mobile.AppStartUp",
    XamarinFormsAppTypeName = "AddView.Mobile.App"
)]

namespace AddView.Mobile.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "AddView", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public partial class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
    }
}
```

Anyone else has this?  Any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

IPushDelegate.OnTokenChanged is only called when the token changes OUTSIDE of RequestAccess.  This really only fires for firebase implementations.